# Don't resize hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make all of the rows in a range a certain height, EXCEPT the hidden rows. As soon as my code gets to `.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)` it jumps to a `Private Sub()`, then comes back and does `.RowHeight = 12` and changes all of my rows, including the hidden ones. How do I prevent it from adjusting the hidden rows?

```
Sub CreateSched()
    
    Worksheets("Schedule").Activate
    
    Sheets("Schedule").Unprotect
    
    Dim t As Range, u As Range
    Set u = Range("F6:F282")
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For Each t In u
            If Not IsEmpty(t.Value) And t = 0 Then
                t.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf t > 0 Then
                t.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next t
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Columns("B:AA").AutoFit
    
    With Worksheets("Schedule").Range("E1:E304")
        .SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
        .RowHeight = 12
    End With
    
    Sheets("Schedule").Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Schedule").Range("E1:E304").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).RowHeight = 12`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - a few suggestions for avoiding select/activate (typically this is not required)

```
Sub CreateSched()
    
    Dim t As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Schedule")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Unprotect
        For Each t In .Range("F6:F282").Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(t.Value) And t = 0 Then
                t.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf t > 0 Then
                t.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next t
        On Error Resume Next '<< in case no visible rows
        .Range("E1:E304").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).RowHeight = 12
        On Error Goto 0 'stop ignoring errors
        .Columns("B:AA").AutoFit
        .Protect
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Really appreciate you doing that. I'm still learning VBA and love to see ways to make it cleaner and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try:

```
With Worksheets("Schedule").Range("E1:E304").SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
    .RowHeight = 12
End With
```

Right now your code is changing all cells to visible, then adjusting all of their heights.

Comment: Thanks. I used Tim Williams' above.

Comment: Hey, don't know if you know about this, but excel-vba doesn't exist anymore. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177/792066